# Cannote find PDB Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, symbols

I did my Hello World! program in Visual Studio 2010 C++, it does work all ok (except that if I enter 2 times it will close, it's normal?)

But there is a little "error message" or whatever that appear in the debug log:

```
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
```

What does that mean?

You can see my code here:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(255, '\n');
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Niko

Answer (score 1):

You could probably download the pdb via WinDbg from the symbol server. See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503 for more information on this.

The following command line will - after you have properly set up your symbol environment - download the pdb for ntdll.dll

```
symchk C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
```

Comment: Thanks :)
I believe this should work, I would use it if there wasn't the option in the parameters! Gracias :P

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you you don't have symbols installed for the system libraries ([pdb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1.aspx) = program database files) .

This isn't a problem, you can still debug your own code.

Comment: Andreas's link (Microsoft Symbol Server) is what you need to get the ntdll.dll pdb

Answer (score 0):

I tried something I saw but I'm not sure if it really works..?
In Debug - Options - Symbols, I checked "Windows Symbol Servers"
Now it says (it's in French so I translated, might not be exactly that on English VS):

```
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll', Symbols charged (informations sources deleted).
```

Should it be ok now?

Comment: If it says 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded then you're ok :)

Comment: Okay! Thank you my friend :) Now it's time I go learn what it actually is lol :P

Comment: For more information on PDB files see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1.aspx (C++) and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903.aspx (C#, F#, VB).